# Unicode Characters in iOS App Name?

Tags: ios, unicode, itunes, app-store-connect

I recently tried submitting my universal app "Blackout" to iTunes connect and, unsurprisingly, found that the app name had already been taken.  So I changed the name to "Blackout ☉☉" because the main character is a set of eyes in the dark.  I got a little popup warning saying that the unicode character "☉" is not allowed.  Does anyone know what characters are allowed?  Searching "flashlight" on the iOS app store yields a number of apps with names containing hearts and circular characters.  Maybe this is a recent change on Apple's end?  I searched the iOS developer documentation and could not find any clarification on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that Apple only allows characters from certain Unicode blocks.

The "☉" symbol I wanted to use is from the Unicode "Miscellaneous Symbols" block (2600–26FF) which is not allowed.

I found a similar symbol "⊙" in the "Mathematical Operators" block (2200–22FF) which was allowed.

I'm not entirely sure which blocks are allowed and which blocks aren't but if you're facing a similar problem, the quickest way to find out is by entering your desired app name into iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked in iTunes Connect your problem solution here you can do that.. just enter it..

"Blackout ©" thats was accepted in iTunes Connect and those uni-code is only accepted in iTunes Connect which is UTF-8 Supported and i suggest to use Mozilla as well for setup app in iTunesConnect.

Any more information need just add comment i will help you out.